# Node.js + MySQL: Time is 2 hours off

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm saving a date / time in MySQL using PhpMyAdmin.
When i look at the date in MySQL it says 21:00
Then i look at the output in node.js, and the time is 19:00.

I'm doing a simple query:

```
connection.query("select * from mytable WHERE id = ?" , [id], function(err,rows){
    if(!err) {
        res.json(rows);
    }           
});
```

Any hints as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying inputting this line on top of your node.js

```
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';
```

You want to try to make timezone uniform across your stack.
It might be the case that timezones on node vs. mysql might be one factor.
try setting both to the same timezone, preferably UTC

Also, take a look at your mysql config:

```
var db_config = {
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : '',
  database : 'xxx',
  timezone: 'utc'  // have you set this?
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea where to start looking. It works!

Comment: glad it worked. I experienced something similar before.